# Istio multiple mTLS certificates in one route

Tags: kubernetes, istio, mtls

I have the following problem. I need to access a webAPP webservice, that also expects an mTLS certificate via a proxy that expects an mTLS certificate. (See diagram at the end)

In my application I set http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort so that the request knows that it has to go through the proxy. The mTLS handling with the proxy is managed by istio.

So far it works without any problems. What's new is that I now have to access a webApp webservice that also expects an mTLS certificate. So, two certificates have to be managed by istio in one route!

I've already read and researched various documentation but haven't found a way to configure this. I'm not sure if that's even possible?!?

Hence my question:

1. Is it even possible that I can configure it like that?
2. And if so, how can I do it?

**client** <------------> **proxy** <-----------> **webapp (webservice)**

Comment: The [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/about/faq/#difference-between-mutual-and-istio-mutual) says `certificate` and not `certificates`. I have not tried to configure multiple client certificates, so I am not sure.